# ListenableFuture or call function to process task result?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

Are there any advantages of processing result using a `ListenableFuture` when submitting a tasks to `ExecutorService` instead of doing it the plain old java way by simply calling a function that processes the results?

**Future:**

```
Future<ScanResult> result = threadPoolExecutor.submit(
    new Callable<ScanResult>() {
        //long running process to get scanResult
        return scanResult;
    });
ScanResult sr = result.get();
```

**OR** use guava `ListenableFuture` to prevent manually `get()` calling.

**Plain Java Way:**

```
threadPoolExecutor.submit(new Callable<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        //long running process to get scanResult
        jobCompleted(scanResult);
        return null;
    }
});
```

Comment: Your examples don't make sense. That doesn't appear to be how you would use a listenable future.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels you're right, it's an example of a normal future, hence the addition in code "(or use guava ListenableFuture to prevent manually get() calling)".

Comment: No that's not what I mean. You don't have any long-running code within the Callable, and it returns nothing, reducing the need to call `get()`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels for clarity i often don't copy & paste full code that you can compile and run. I'll add a little comment to my question to make it a bit clearer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked on Guava Concurrency or `ListenableFuture` but I think the main advantage is generic **event based program design** which is easier to understand and visualize than manually triggering code based on events.

`Future.get()` is a blocking method so you are anyhow blocked till `Callable` is complete so you are coupling two independent code execution paths into a single execution path. Adding listener decouples them and couples them logically based on event.

Also as per [github link](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained), it is strongly advised to use it and I guess reason for it might be additional services supported by `ListenableFuture` that might not be present in plain `Future`.

Hope it helps !!

Comment: Cheers! I get your point about a normal future. But i fail to see benefits of using ListenableFuture over the old java way listeners. ListenableFuture also decouples the execution path just like a listener (ie no need to call the blocking future.get). Maybe i'm overlooking something very simple?